# Interaction terms in Cox model - Why does the result when I multiply variables myself?

Tags: r, regression, survival, multivariate-analysis, interaction

I have a data set with the following variables:

`outcome`: outcome (value: 0,1)

`time`

`chemical1`: exposure level of chemical 1 (value: 1,2,3)

`chemical2`: exposure level of chemical 2 (value: 1,2,3)

`confounders`: other confounding variables.

I hope to evaluate the interaction between `chemical1` and `chemical2` in cox regression:

```
coxph(Surv(time, outcome) ~ chemical1 * chemical2 + confounders, data = data)
```

The result is as following:

```
                                           coef exp(coef)  se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|) 
factor(chemical1)3:factor(chemical2)3  0.734954  2.085386  0.483811  1.519  0.12874  

                                         exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
factor(chemical1)3:factor(chemical2)3    2.0854     0.4795    0.8079     5.383
```

(Other rows omitted)

I created another variable `interaction`.
This variable has value 0 when both `chrmical1` and `chemical2` are 1, value `1` when both are 3.

I plug this value into the regression:

```
coxph(Surv(time, outcome) ~ interaction + confounders, data = data)
```

The results:

```
                           coef exp(coef)  se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)    
factor(interaction)1  1.551730  4.719627  0.194017  7.998 1.27e-15 ***

                         exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
factor(interaction)1    4.7196     0.2119    3.2267     6.903
```

Could somebody help explain why the values beween `interaction` and `factor(chemical1)3:factor(chemical2)3` is different? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The way you explain what you have done, the 2 models are substantially different.

The first model, with the `chemical1 * chemical2` term, implies (along with effects of the `confounders`) 2 "main effects" for each of the `chemical`s, representing differences for each chemical of level `2` and level `3` from its level `1`. It also produces interaction terms between the `chemical`s for each pair of their levels `2` and `3`.

The second model *only* adds to the `confounders` a *single* interaction term, between the 2 `chemical`s each at level `3`. It omits the "main effects" and the other interaction terms.

If you run 2 models with different sets of predictors, you should expect to get different results between them for any predictor that you include in both. This is an example of [omitted-variable bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omitted-variable_bias), which can happen even in ordinary least-squares regression and can be even more troublesome in Cox regressions.